# cloudformation - json-sed not working for environment variables

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, sed, aws-cloudformation

I am working on aws cloud formation and  trying to replace the sentence discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: [127.0.0.1] using sed and json but it is not reading value stored under  $SPARK_MASTER_IP $Worker1 .

```
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: [127.0.0.1]
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["10.100.53.195 ","10.100.52.124 "]

echo $Worker1
10.100.53.185

echo $SPARK_MASTER_IP
10.100.53.218

"su - root -c 'sed -i -e \"s/discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: \\[127\\.0\\.0\\.1\\]/discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: \\[\\\"$SPARK_MASTER_IP\\\",\\\"$Worker1\\\"\\]/g\" /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml'\n",
```

but the output of the above command is

```
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["",""]
```

Pls help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're doing with all the escaping, although this should work:

```
sed -i 's/discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: \[127\.0\.0\.1\]/discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: \['\"$SPARK_MASTER_IP\"','\"$Worker1\"'\]/g'
```

**Multi-line**:

```
sed -i 's/discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: '\
'\[127\.0\.0\.1\]/discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: '\
'\['\"$SPARK_MASTER_IP\"','\"$Worker1\"'\]/g'
```

**Result**:

```
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["10.100.53.185","10.100.53.218"]
```

*The `-e` option shouldn't be needed since there's nothing appended to the end of the command.

Comment: I am working on cloudformation and its working if i run the command as such, but when i add the command to aws cloud formation template it is not working., no error also

Comment: You could try wrapping it like so perhaps `su - root -c "$( ... )"`, and the `sed` command would go where the `...` is within the brackets. It also might be a matter of needing to export or source your `env` variables (the ones that are not showing)...